# Google Chart - Bar chart with label underneath

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to create something close to this using Google Chart API:

[image: what i'm trying to do]

So far, I've got this:

```
<img src="//chart.googleapis.com/chart?
chbh=a
&chs=461x337
&cht=bvg
&chco=323232,7bc247&c
&chd=e:zM,Mz" width="461" height="337" alt="" />
```

Which generates this

http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/c2VAP/

Which is almost there, but I can't figure out how / if I can add a label underneath the bars?

Comment: Do you have to use the Image Chart API (which is now deprecated)?  If not, here's an example of that chart duplicated with the Visualization API Interactive charts: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/3vaEE/.

Comment: Not tied to the image chart api (I wasn't sure if it had been depreciated) so that looks like a better option!

Comment: FYI, I removed a bunch of the default features from that chart to make it match the image you put up.  Here's what it looks like without the features removed: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/3vaEE/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get labels like that, you have to make a few changes.  Set the following chart parameters:

```
cht=bvs                // create a stacked chart
chd=zM__,__Mz          // insert null values for the opposite data points
chxt=x                 // create an x-axis
hxl=0:|Label+1|Label+2 // set the labels on the x-axis ("+" translates to a space)
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/c2VAP/2/